# Объект в ооп

Tags: ооп, c#, объекты

Я не могу понять смысл "объекта" в ооп (изучаю C#) ! Вот например у меня есть класс  (не статический) `SuperClass` у этого класса есть поля и методы (публичные):

```
int a;  
string str;  
void func();
```

Что бы мне всё это использовать нужно создать экземпляр этого класса (объект):

```
SuperClass obj1 = new SuperClass();
```

Но obj1 - это **ссылка** на объект, которая хранится в стеке, а объект как-то попадает в управляемую кучу, так где же мой объект и что он делает ?
Я вообще понимаю *экземпляр класса* например этот мой obj1 как ключ к полям и методам определенного класса ибо без него я ничего не смогу сделать ...

Comment: @SoloMio извините, пишу здесь - в вашем ответе закончились комментарии. Про "декларация" и "идентификатор" - потому что в языке у этих слов есть другие значения, а то, что вы назвали этими словами, называется по-другому

Comment: @Dream, ок, разберемся и с этим

Answer (score 3):

> Но obj1 - это ссилка на объект, которая хранится в стеке, а объект как-то попадает в управляемую кучу, так где же мой объект и что он делает ?

Объект создается в куче, когда вы вызываете конструктор, после чего вы получаете ссылку на этот объект. Как указатель на объект класса в C++, если так будет понятнее.

Возьмите книгу CLR via C# и изучайте. Судя по вопросу, изучение языка в частности (тут 
даже целая платформа) и ООП в целом с наскоку у вас не получится.

Comment: Что посоветуете почитать по C# где без воды и всё по делу ?

Comment: > Возьмите книгу CLR via C#

Comment: Если сходу не поймете Рихтера, прочитайте сперва [это][1]. Пусть вас не смущает название и стиль, там очень наглядно объясняется суть ООП в C#.

Еще одна неплохая книга - Visual C# 2008 Базовый курс (Уотсон, Нейгел, Педерсен, Д.Рид, Скиннер, Уайт)

  [1]: http://download.microsoft.com/documents/rus/msdn/c_sharp2.pdf

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать причину минуса. Вроде фигни не писал.

Answer (score -2):

> Но obj1 - это ссилка на объект, которая хранится в стеке, а объект как-то попадает в управляемую кучу, так где же мой объект и что он делает ?

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.
Ваш объект размещен в той самой управляемой куче (если его описание задекларировано именно с идентификатором class, а не struct).
И попадает он туда не "как-то", а именно благодаря тому, что вы объявили его как класс. Написали бы Struct, и ваш новосозданный объект разместился бы на стеке, а не в куче.
Ссылка, кстати, через "Ы" пишется. Ибо "ссылать".

> и что он делает

Что ваш объект делает - зависит исключительно от того, какие обязанности вы на его возложите. 
Скажете грядки поливать, будет грядки поливать, скажете полоть, будет полоть. Все очень просто.

Comment: Спасибо вам ...

Comment: Да нема за що. Учитесь, читайте, развивайтесь, гуглите, задавайте умные вопросы.

Comment: Размещение value types в `C#` на стеке или в куче — [это сугубо деталь реализации,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) поэтому ваше утверждение про размещение `struct'ов` в куче неверно.

Comment: @SoloMio извините, но это аццкая чепуха

Comment: @DreamChild почему чипуха ?

Comment: @Paveladro потому что отвечавший сам имеет очень слабое представление о том, о чем пытается вам рассказать. В частности, утверждение про то, что value-типы хранятся в стеке. Это далеко не всегда так. Более того, тут так и не был дан ответ непосредственно на ваш вопрос. Я уже не говорю о фактических ошибках типа "идентификатор class" и  не относящейся к делу ерунде про грядки

Comment: Скажите, если я напишу obj1.а = 50; то перименная "a" со значением "50" будет хранится в стеке или внутри объкта в куче ?

Comment: Кто-то может подсказать ?

Comment: @Paveladro Я бы на вашем месте последовал бы совету @Flammable, поскольку вот этот ваш вопрос про `obj1.a` показывает, что вы несколько плаваете в матчасти.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать человеку, задающему такие вопросы читать Рихтера очень рано. Сломает себе голову и просто бросит C#. Рихтера нужно читать, уже имея какую-то базу.

Comment: ой господи, ну кошмар вообще. сказал, что Value types на стеке хранятся. Все, минус 100500 теперь.

Comment: @SoloMio дело не только и не столько в этом, сколько в том, что человек, пытающийся кого-то чему-то учить, сам должен хорошо понимать то,  что рассказывает. Если вы делаете что-то для себя, то должны быть внимательны. Если кого-то учите, то внимательны вдвойне. Вы же в своем ответе, к сожалению, а) даете неверную информацию б) оперируете неправильными терминами (да-да, это тоже важно, когда, скажем, хирург называет скальпель скальпелем, а не "этой хреновиной" в) вообще мало говорите по сути

Comment: @DreamChild, согласен со всем кроме третьего пункта. На вопрос я отвечал по-сути. Автор спрашивал где находится его объект и что он делает. И на этот вопрос я ответил. Да, я не провел достаточно исследований и мое утверждение было неверным. Насчет терминологии. Почему Вы считаете, что слова делкрация и идентификатор были использованы в неверном контексте?